# JavaScript непонятный синтаксис

Tags: javascript

В просторах интернета встретил функцию, которая возвращала такое значение:

```
return ( A < B ? +1 :
(A > B ? -1 : 0)) * [-1,1][+!!reverse];
```

Что тут `* [-1,1][+!!reverse]` происходит?

На что мы умножаем и что это `+!!reverse` делает ?
Именно что `+` дает?

Answer (score 2):

[-1,1] - массив

[-1,1][0] - берем первый член массива

!!reverse - приводим reverse к bool

+reverse - приводим reverse к int

т.е. умножаем на один из членов массива (-1, либо 1) в зависимости от значения переменной reverse

Answer (score 2):

Выражение  **+!!reverse** всегда дает либо 0 либо 1 (числовой эквивалент **true/false** если угодно). А плюс позволяет как раз привести результат выражения **!!reverse** к числу вне зависимости от того, чем оно было изначально (строкой, целым числом, числом с плавающей точкой, **null** или чем-то еще). По сути необходимость в таком в общем-то корявом синтаксисе свидетельствует о некоторой неуклюжести JavaScrip (впрочем, это диктуется динамической типизацией этого языка)

Например:

```
+!!true // 1
!!true  // true

+!!false // 0
!!false //false

+!!null // 0
!!null // false

+!!undefined// 0
!!undefined// false

+!!'some' //  1
!!'some' // true

+!!'10' // 1
!!'10'  // true

+!!10 // 1
!!10  // true
```

Comment: В JS разбираюсь как свинья в апельсинах, но такого "извращения" себе даже представить не смог бы! PHP нервно курит в сторонке :)) Спс за позновательный ответ (и вопрос, конечно) Всем плюсую в репу.

Comment: @MDJHD чуть более читабельным (но менее лаконичным) будет такой вариант: 
   

    Number(!!something)